# Excepcion User-Unhandled API

Tags: c#, api

Estoy desarrollando una API en C#, con el modelo MVC y me esta lanzando una excepción al llamar al servicio en el controller. La excepción en cuestión es esta:

> Exception User-Unhandled.
> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida
> como instancia de un objeto.'

Sucede apenas llama a la interfaz de servicio, les muestro como tengo la API construida.

**Controller:**

```
public class ExcelController : BaseApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Servicio de Excel
        /// </summary>
        private IServicioExcel _servicioExcel { get; set; }

        public ExcelController()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// <param name="servicioVentas">Servicio de reportes en Excel.</param>
        public ExcelController(IServicioExcel servicioExcel)
        {
            this._servicioExcel = servicioExcel;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public void Get()
        {
            _servicioExcel.Get();
        }
}
```

**Interfaz del servicio**

```
public interface IServicioExcel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Genera un archivo Excel a partir de una lista de objetos
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    void Get();
}
```

**Servicio**

```
public void Get()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Hay otros metodos y verbos pero todos arrojan la misma exepción al llamar a la linea del controller que tiene la interfaz. En este caso que deje el Get como ejemplo seria en la línea:

> _servicioExcel.Get();

Y no puedo obtener mas información sobre que es ese error, y tampoco se me ocurre que probar ya que no se bien por que esta pasando. Alguien me podría dar una mano! Gracias.

Comment: Claramente, hay algo que es null, donde? Así a bote pronto (trabajo con apis tambien) te diria que no veo la ruta para acceder a la llamada de tu api. La ruta tiene que estar en el controlador

Comment: Hola Iria! Gracias por la respuesta. Te referis a algo como esto?
**[Route("api/Reporte/GenerarExcel")]**. Porque si lo hago en otros verbos pero ese lo deje simple para que no se alarge la pregunta.

Comment: si, eso es, cuando haces un debugging donde peta exactamente?

Comment: En la ultima cite lo aclare mas por las dudas, pero aca te lo dejo tambien:
**_servicioExcel.Get();**

Comment: El error es porque `_servicioExcel` es nulo.  Asegurate de tener una clase que implemente la interface `IServicioExcel`. Por ejemplo: `public class MiServicioExcel : IServicioExcel {...}` y también asegurate de crear una instancia de `IServicioExcel _servicioExcel = new MiServicioExcel(...);` previo a su uso, o mapearla en el Inyector de Dependencias;

Answer (score 2):

Estás llamando al Get, con el verbo Get, luego esperas recibir algo, sin embargo, la función la tienes declarada de tipo void, con lo que no devuelve nada. A mayores, esta función está sin implementar y arroja una excepción. Aquí tienes varias cosas que solucionar, y tampoco veo donde escribes la respuesta, lo que devuelve la llamada api. Tu problema es que el codigo es muy preliminar, esta muy a medias, continua escribiendo, y solucionaras muchos de tus problemas.

Ejemplo de código que funciona: .NET core 3.1

```
private readonly IService _service;
/*codigo to setup the basis, route, responses and so on...*/
public Controller(IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<bool> Get()
    {
        var response = await _service.Get();
        return response;
    }
```

eso en el controller,  en startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
/*codigo vario*/
services.AddScoped<IService, Service>();
/* mas codigo*/

        AddHttpClient(services, "Service", Configuration.GetValue<string>("ServiceSettings:BaseUrl"));
        services.AddTransient<Service>();}
```

AddHttpClient es un metodo para generar httpcontext y pasarlo, saco los datos de configuracion

Comment: Ese ejemplo que deje en la llamada del Get era para no pasar todo el código y que quede muy larga la pregunta. Tengo métodos que si esperan recibir algo y devuelven algo bien pero arroja igual la exepción. No es ese el problema

Comment: falta mas codigo para poder dar una respuesta, pero el throw ... podias haber puesto /* codigo*/, pero está claramente entonces en la línea donde accedes al servicio